# Pyhon3, как использовать pass для входа на сайт?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу клиент для входа на сайт, туда надо отправить через **POST** логин и пароль. Проблема заключается в том, что название логина *"login"* а вот пароля *"pass"*. Из-за этого при запуска кода, питон ругается на **pass** (пишет invalid syntax)  
Ругается на **pass=** в этой строчке:

```
data = dict(email='Login', pass='Password' )
```

Какой есть способ показать питону, что **pass** это *не оператор*, а *название*?

Comment: Почему бы не `data = {'email': 'Login', 'pass': 'Password'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать `data = dict({'email': 'Login', 'pass': 'Password'})`

Спасибо за ответ в комментарии **andreymal** !

Comment: И всё же почему бы не `data = {'email': 'Login', 'pass': 'Password'}` зачем вам `dict()` :\

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/197341)

Comment: @MedvedevDev это безусловно ответом является. Следует только ещё dict() стереть. Вопрос: «как записать `dict(pass=1)` (что SyntaxError вызывает, так как pass зарезервирован в Питоне», ответ `{'pass': 1}`